# tensorflow read image vs opencv read image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, tensorflow

When I was trying to check the data read by tensorflow and opencv, I found that the data read by tensorflow and opencv is different for the same image (same position and channel as well). Converting image channel doesn't work since their color values are different.

Here is the image I used:

[image]

My code:

```
aa = cv2.imread(path) 
tf1 = tf.read_file(path) 
tf2 = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf1, channels=3) 
atf2 = tf.Session().run(tf2)
```

Here is the sample results I got.

[image: Here is the sample results I got]

Comment: Please edit your post to include also the code you used to read the images.

Comment: can you check whether the image has a color profile other than sRGB (adobeRGB?) openCV does not handle color profiles at all.

Comment: @mikkola  Here is the code:
aa = cv2.imread(path) 
tf1 = tf.read_file(path)
tf2 = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf1, channels=3)
atf2 = tf.Session().run(tf2)

Comment: @Micka Those images are cropped and written by opencv, I think there is no color profile for them.

Comment: I can't reproduce this using your code with any of the images I have on hand, can you load the images somewhere so we can test?

Comment: @BHawk Here is the test image I used https://ibb.co/f0BVCx

Comment: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/2293

Comment: What OS you use ?

Comment: @Link Fedora release 25, tensorflow 1.4.0, opencv 3.4.0